# React Native Android Application Security check shows outgoing traffic to googleapis.com

Tags: android, react-native, android-security, android-googleapiclient

I have developed ReactNative mobile application, When I run security tests using [ImmuniWeb] report shows me that my application makes post request to 'https://www.googleapis.com/experimentsandconfigs/v1/getExperimentsAndConfigs'[1](https://www.immuniweb.com/mobile/?id=N4S8XrET) I have not used any of the google analytical tools or any other google cloud services in my application.
One of the Example request is traced as below.

```
Date/Time: 16.05.2020 17:27 CEST
Requested URL: https://www.googleapis.com/experimentsandconfigs/v1/getExperimentsAndConfigs
Requested HTTP Headers:
User-Agent: Android/com.google.android.gms/16089022 (generic_x86 OSM1.180201.031); gzip
content-length: 1069
content-type: application/x-protobuf
Host: www.googleapis.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Response HTTP Headers:
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Sat, 16 May 2020 15:27:24 GMT
Expires: Sat, 16 May 2020 15:27:24 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Server: sffe
X-XSS-Protection: 0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Alt-Svc: h3-27=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-25=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
content-length: 49581
```

I have also created dummy app to check the same it is reporting the same issue in security report.
you can see the full report here. [Security Report](https://www.immuniweb.com/mobile/?id=N4S8XrET)
Can anyone please help me solving this? Thanks in advance.